# Change timestamp field to date in postgres on table having 120 million records - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, psql

I have table with 120 million, table schema is mentioned below,

```
t.integer  "invoice_number",        default: -1
t.text     "url"
t.boolean  "image",           default: false
t.integer  "client_id"
t.integer  "team_id"
t.datetime "invoice_date"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "count"
```

currently, I have unique index on `url`, `client_id`, `team_id`, `invoice_date` and `user_id`. Any query based on this is much more time taking.

If I change the type of `invoice_date` to date, would that have any performance improvement on queries?

Which is the safest way to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you what impact the change has on performance without a thorough knowledge of your database and applications, even though I think the differences are very small.

I strongly recommend you to create a copy of your database first, and test the most important queries and statement. You can compare performance with [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html) in both databases.

If you have general performance issues, you should use `EXPLAIN` as well to identify this leaks. You can probably get more performance out of creating indexes, materialized views, better statistics, etc. than by changing the type of a single column.

You should use the copy to measure the migration time as well. An `ALTER TABLE` statement on a large table may take a *long* time. So you can estimate possible downtimes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for certain, but it is very unlikely that changing from `timestamp` to `date` will bring a huge performance improvement.

Odds are that either your queries should be improved or you are missing an index.

Try to figure out which queries are slow and work on them.